# Error thrown for non existing function in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ program and on execution, I face the following error :

system was not declared in this scope

```
#include <iostream>
#include "commands.h"

using namespace std;


void retrieveDataset(const char* input) 
{
const char* command = "wget ";
std::string buf(command);
buf.append(input);
const char * c = buf.c_str();
system(c);
}

void generateInputLayer(const char* input)
{
const char * start = "generateNetCDF -d gl_input -i ";
std::string buf(start);
buf.append(input);
const char * end = " -o gl_input.nc -f features_input -s samples_input -c";
buf.append(end);
const char * c = buf.c_str();
system(c);
}

void generateOutputLayer(const char * input)
{
const char * start = "generateNetCDF -d gl_output -i ";
std::string buf(start);
buf.append(input);
const char * end = " -o gl_output.nc -f features_output -s samples_input -c";
buf.append(end);
const char * c = buf.c_str();
system(c);
}

void train(int batchSize, int num_epochs)
{
const char * start = "train -c config.json -i gl_input.nc -o gl_output.nc -n gl.nc -b ";
std::string buf(start);
std::string batchString = std::to_string(batchSize);
std::string epochString = std::to_string(num_epochs);
char const *b = batchString.c_str();
char const *e = epochString.c_str();
buf.append(b);
const char * middle =  " -e ";
buf.append(middle);
buf.append(e);
const char * c = buf.c_str();
std::cout << c;
system(c);
}

void predict(int num_recommendations, const char * input) 
{
const char * start = "predict -b 1024 -d gl -i features_input -o features_output -k ";
std::string buf(start);
std::string recString = std::to_string(num_recommendations);
char const *r = recString.c_str();
buf.append(r);
const char * next = " -n gl.nc -f ";
buf.append(next);
buf.append(input);
const char * last = " -s recs -r ";
buf.append(last);
buf.append(input);
const char * c = buf.c_str();
system(c);
}
```

The system is throwing me the error : error: ‘system’ was not declared in this scope system(c);
where ever the system(c) is in the code.

Commands.h file is below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

void retrieveDataset(const char* input);
void generateInputLayer(const char* input);
void generateOutputLayer(const char * input);
void train(int batchSize, int num_epochs);
void predict(int num_recommendations, const char * input);
```

Kindly help. New to C++

Comment: Please add [`#include <stdlib.h>`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) - or `#include <cstdlib>` since you mention C++.

Comment: Just to help you understand an important distinction: this is not an error that happened "on execution". Your code was never executed at all! This is a _compile-time_ error, which as Ken pointed out was caused by a missing header.

Comment: missing declaration. You can use  your  IDE help or this site: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/ to check which headers you do need.